# slf4j File Not Found error when building uberwar

Tags: clojure, ring, compojure

I would like to understand why my Ring application is attempting to open the log file at compile time.

I have a webservice in Compojure and Ring.  The application works without issue but whenever I compile the application to an uberwar or run `lein ring server` I get the below error from slf4j.

I don't understand what is causing the Clojure compiler to attempt to access this log file during compilation.  The only clue which I have is that it only started happening when I included the Korma library.

If I create the directory I can get rid of the error, however, I want to understand why the application is attempting to open the log file at compile time.

```
log4j:ERROR setFile(null,true) call failed.
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /var/log/ege/myservice/myservice.log (No such file or directory)
        at java.io.FileOutputStream.open0(Native Method)
        at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(FileOutputStream.java:270)
        at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:213)
        at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:133)
        at org.apache.log4j.FileAppender.setFile(FileAppender.java:294)
        at org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender.setFile(RollingFileAppender.java:207)
        at org.apache.log4j.FileAppender.activateOptions(FileAppender.java:165)
        at org.apache.log4j.config.PropertySetter.activate(PropertySetter.java:307)
        at org.apache.log4j.config.PropertySetter.setProperties(PropertySetter.java:172)
        at org.apache.log4j.config.PropertySetter.setProperties(PropertySetter.java:104)
        at org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.parseAppender(PropertyConfigurator.java:809)
        at org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.parseCategory(PropertyConfigurator.java:735)
        at org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.configureRootCategory(PropertyConfigurator.java:615)
        at org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.doConfigure(PropertyConfigurator.java:502)
```

Comment: do you have log4j.properties or log4j.xml in your src/ directory or other classpath?

Comment: Yup, I have the log4j.properties file in the src directory.

Answer (score 1):

log4j configuration is a runtime configuration of your app. Korma uses log4j configuration for its usage in runtime. So, it's not surprising that when running `lein ring server`, korma uses log4j configuration for its logging and the log4j logging throws error cause it can not find the log directory.

As for the error thrown during `lein check` or `lein ring war`. Maybe you have some forms which attempts to connect to database or even do some query to your database in top-level of some of your namespaces.

maybe you have something like this:

```
(ns my-app.db
    (:use korma.db)
    (:use korma.core))

(def db  (create-db (mysql {:db "my_db"
                        :user "root"
                        :password ""})))



;; this form below attempts to get a db connection
(def conn (get-connection db))

(defentity users)

;; this form below attempts to query the database
(select users)
```

when clojure compiles, it executes every form, thus, clojure connects to db or query the db. In other words, clojure runs a part of your app during compilation.

#### unrelated note

Everything above aside, you should separate the log4j configuration or any other runtime-configs for development environment and production environment.

I usually separate development environment and production environment configuration using `:profiles` in `project.clj`.

```
:profiles
   {:production
      {:ring
         {:open-browser? false, :stacktraces? false, :auto-reload? false}
       :source-paths ["prod-config"]}
    :dev
      {:dependencies [[ring-mock "0.1.5"] [ring/ring-devel "1.3.1"]]
       :source-paths ["dev-config"]}}
```

I put my development's log4j.properties in `dev-config` dir and production's log4j.properties in `prod-config` dir.